# Error al recibir error: function (data){}

Tags: ajax, laravel-6

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este mensaje me manda cuando intento probar que funciona mi validación.

desde el controller retorno un mensaje de error cuando recibo el error

$email = $request->get('email');

```
       if ( $existe = user::where('email', '=',$email)->exists()) {
           
           $data  = array(
                    'status'    =>  'Error',
                    'code'     =>  '400',
                    'message'  =>  'EL EMAIL YA HA SIDO REGISTRADO'
                ); 

            return response()->json($data, $data['message']);
```

Esto es lo que trato de mandar al ajax y trato de hacer que me muestre el siguiente alert con el mensaje que envío

```
            error: function (data) {
                var stringified = JSON.stringify(data);
                var parsedObj = JSON.parse(stringified);

                alert(parsedObj)

                
              }
```

No se que estoy mandando mal

Comment: Hazle un JSON.stringify pero a data y nos comentas

Comment: de pasada ponle un  `console.log(data);` y mira el contenido y formato de tu respuesta del controlador.

Comment: exception: "Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError"
file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\BuzonItlac\vendor\symfony\http-foundation\JsonResponse.php"
line: 42
message: "Argument 2 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse::__construct() must be of the type integer, string given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\BuzonItlac\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse.php on line 31"